# Рабочий код не проходит тесты

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть задачка с телефонной книгой. Я её не мог решить ибо думал, что у меня какие-то проблемы, но я отдебажил код через браузер и просмотрел какие значение в коде фигурируют и какие результаты выдают. В общем - результаты положительные, но тесты написаные куратором курса они не проходят(При этом результаты полностью совпадают). Посмотрите пожалуйста и скажите или это тесты неправильные или я неправильный код написал.
Вот код самой програмки:

```
// Телефонная книга
var phoneBook = [];

/**
* @param {String} command
* @returns {*} - результат зависит от команды
*/
module.exports = function (command) {
    if (command.includes('ADD')) ADD(command);
    else if (command.includes('REMOVE_PHONE')) REMOVE_PHONE(command);
    else SHOW();
};

function ADD(data) {
    var arr = data.split(' ');

    if (phoneBook.length == 0) {
        phoneBook = [...phoneBook, { name: arr[1], phones: arr[2] }];
    }
    else {
        phoneBook.forEach(i => {
            if (i.name.includes(arr[1])) {
                i.phones += ',' + arr[2];
            }
            else {
                phoneBook = [...phoneBook, { name: arr[1], phones: arr[2] }];
            }
        })
    }
}

function REMOVE_PHONE(data) {
    var arr = data.split(' ');
    var bool = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < phoneBook.length; i++) {
        if (phoneBook[i].phones.includes(arr[1] + ',')) {
            phoneBook[i].phones = phoneBook[i].phones.replace(arr[1] + ',', '');
            bool = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (phoneBook[i].phones.includes(arr[1])) {
            phoneBook[i].phones = phoneBook[i].phones.replace(arr[1], '');
            bool = true;
            break;
        }
        else bool = false;
    }
    return bool;
}

function SHOW() {
    var resultStr = '';
    var result = [];
    phoneBook.forEach(i => {
        resultStr = i.name + ': ';
        if (i.phones != '') {
            resultStr += i.phones.split(',').join(', ');
            result.push(resultStr);
        }
    })
    return result;
}
```

Код тестов:

```
// Встроенный в Node.JS модуль для проверок
var assert = require('assert');

// Подключаем свою функцию
var phoneBook = require('./index.js');

// Добавляем телефоны контакту Ivan
phoneBook('ADD Ivan 555-10-01,555-10-03');
phoneBook('ADD Ivan 555-10-02');

// Проверка работы функции SHOW
assert.deepStrictEqual(
    // Получаем содержимое телефонной книги
    phoneBook('SHOW'),
    [
        'Ivan: 555-10-01, 555-10-03, 555-10-02'
    ],
    'В телефонной книге: "Ivan: 555-10-01, 555-10-03, 555-10-02"'
);

// Проверка работы функции REMOVE_PHONE
assert.strictEqual(
    // Удаляем телефон 555-10-03
    phoneBook('REMOVE_PHONE 555-10-03'),
   true,
   'Телефон 555-10-03 успешно удален'
);
// Добавляем новый контакт
phoneBook('ADD Alex 555-20-01');

// Проверка работы функции SHOW
assert.deepStrictEqual(
    // Получаем содержимое телефонной книги
    phoneBook('SHOW'),
    [
        'Alex: 555-20-01',
        'Ivan: 555-10-01, 555-10-02'
    ],
    'В телефонной книге: "Alex: 555-20-01", "Ivan: 555-10-01, 555-10-02"'
);

// Удаляем телефон
phoneBook('REMOVE_PHONE 555-20-01');

// Проверка работы функции SHOW
assert.deepStrictEqual(
    // Получаем содержимое телефонной книги
    phoneBook('SHOW'),
    [
        'Ivan: 555-10-01, 555-10-02'
    ],
    'В телефонной книге: "Ivan: 555-10-01, 555-10-02"'
);

console.info('OK!');
```

Comment: Думаю вы могли бы вполне воспроизвести пример тут безо всяких там файлов

Comment: Имеете введу так же как и предыдущий код оформил, я вас правильно понял?

Comment: Хорошо оформленный вопрос залог получения хорошего ответа

Comment: Не понятно как у вас Alex оказался вдруг в начале массива

Comment: @Grundy может, чтоит закрыть как [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=REMOVE_PHONE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Постановка вашей задачи](https://github.com/dm-gthb/tasks/blob/master/4/README.md) заканчивается словами

> В этой задаче удобно разбить операции над телефонной книгой на
> отдельные функции. Их следует вызывать для конкретной операции. При
> использовании такой декомпозиции важно не забыть вернуть результат
> выполнения функции. Иначе основная функция будет возвращать undefined.

С этого и начнём.

```
var phoneBook = [];

module.exports = function (command) {
    if (command.includes('ADD')) ADD(command);
    else if (command.includes('REMOVE_PHONE')) REMOVE_PHONE(command);
    else SHOW();
};
```

Где `return`? Где три `return`?

Использовать `command.includes` не эффективно. Нужно сделать `const [cmd, ...cmdArgs] = 'ADD Alex 555-20-01'.split(/\s/)` и разбросать вызовы через switch/case, не забыв про return.

```
function ADD(data) {
    var arr = data.split(' ');

    if (phoneBook.length == 0) {
        phoneBook = [...phoneBook, { name: arr[1], phones: arr[2] }];
    }
```

^ зачем этот if?

```
    else {
        phoneBook.forEach(i => {
            if (i.name.includes(arr[1])) {
```

^ этот includes приведёт к тому, что при наличии контактов "IVAN1" и "IVAN2" новый контакт "IVAN" запишется в оба, а не создаст новый.

```
                i.phones += ',' + arr[2];
            }
            else {
                phoneBook = [...phoneBook, { name: arr[1], phones: arr[2] }];
            }
        })
    }
}
```

^ в цикле не помешал бы break, да и поиск по словарю имён бы не помешал. телефоны можно split по запятой и хранить в массиве. искать-удалять стало бы в разы проще. и словарь телефонов бы не помешал, но это чуть выше beginer level.

```
function REMOVE_PHONE(data) {
    var arr = data.split(' ');
    var bool = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < phoneBook.length; i++) {
        if (phoneBook[i].phones.includes(arr[1] + ',')) {
            phoneBook[i].phones = phoneBook[i].phones.replace(arr[1] + ',', '');
            bool = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (phoneBook[i].phones.includes(arr[1])) {
            phoneBook[i].phones = phoneBook[i].phones.replace(arr[1], '');
            bool = true;
            break;
        }
        else bool = false;
    }
    return bool;
}
```

^ снова безумный includes - удаляя телефон "5" удалим все телефоны содержащие "5". и выковыривание телефонов с болью. телефоны должны храниться в массиве. и в цикле `item.phones = item.phones.filter((itemPhone) => itemPhone !== data)`

```
function SHOW() {
    var resultStr = '';
    var result = [];
    phoneBook.forEach(i => {
        resultStr = i.name + ': ';
        if (i.phones != '') {
            resultStr += i.phones.split(',').join(', ');
            result.push(resultStr);
        }
    })
    return result;
}
```

сортировки нет, `return result.sort();`. `reduce` вместо `forEach`.

---

Обращаю ваше внимание, что перед созданием вопроса вы должны были выполнить поиск существующих вопросов и ответов. [Вы удивитесь...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=REMOVE_PHONE)

Answer (score 0):

Решение так себе натянуто за уши.

Пишу в ответ поскольку с целью дальнейшего исправления при получении дополнительной информации.

1. Добавьте протоколы добавления и удаления номеров. Вижу что можно добавлять несколько номеров в контакте за раз. Как на счёт удаления?
2. Ваш вывод не отсортирован по имени, и не понятно почему ваши ответы совпадают.

Рекомендации. Раз уже вы храните контакты в в объекте, то рекомендую номера хранить в массиве. И осуществлять поиск номера в массиве, а не в строке проверяя на наличии его с запятой и без.